# Python issue with incorrectly formated strings that contains \x

Tags: python, string, unicode

At some point our python script receives string like that:

```
In [1]: ab = 'asd\xeffe\ctive'

In [2]: print ab
asd�fe\ctve \ \\ \\\k\\\
```

Data is damaged we need escape \x to be properly interpreted as \x but \c has not special meaning in string thus must be intact.

So far the closest solution I found is do something like:

```
In [1]: ab = 'asd\xeffe\ctve \\ \\\\ \\\\\\k\\\\\\'

In [2]: print ab.encode('string-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').replace("\\'", "'")

asd\xeffe\ctve \ \\ \\\k\\\
```

Output taken from IPython, I assumed that ab is a string not unicode string (in the later case we would have to do something like that:

```
def escape_string(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = s.encode('string-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').replace("\\'", "'")
    elif isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').replace("\\'", "'")
    return s
```

Comment: One (fragile!) hack is to use `repr`, i.e. `repr(s)[1:-1]`.

Comment: don't call `__repr__` directly. it's spelled `repr(ab)`.

Comment: It makes much more sense to fix this at the source of the string data. Could you elaborate on why you are receiving data in the form `ab = 'asd\xeffe\ctive'` in the first place (as opposed to properly sanitized `ab = 'asd\\xeffe\\ctive'`)?

Comment: If we knew how that broken data enters our system, I wouldn't ask that question, would I? :) I totally agree we need fix a source but so far source is mysterious. We just can't reproduce whatever our users are doing.

Comment: @Drachenfels: are you aware that string-escape translates the newline character to '\\n' (two characters) as well as all other valid escapes?

Comment: Well I was not aware in fact, but those replaces in my sample are the way to fix all other 'escapes' that we don't need. I know it's very, very fragile and poor way to fix corrupted data. But well. If we cant fix the source we need to live with what we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\\'` is the same as `'\x5c'`. It is just two different ways to write the backslash character as a *Python string literal*.

These literal strings: `r'\c'`, `'\\c'`, `'\x5cc'`, `'\x5c\x63'` are *identical* `str` objects in memory.

`'\xef'` is a single byte (`239` as an integer), but `r'\xef'` (same as `'\\xef'`) is a 4-byte string: `'\x5c\x78\x65\x66'`.

If `s[0]` returns `'\xef'` then it is what `s` object actually contains. If it is wrong then fix the source of the data.

---

Note: `string-escape` also escapes `\n` and the like:

```py
>>> print u'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''.encode('unicode-escape')
\xef\\c\\\u2603"'\u2603\u2603"'\n\xa0
>>> print b'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''.encode('string-escape')
\xef\\c\\\\N{SNOWMAN}"\'\xe2\x98\x83\\u2603"\'\n\xa0
```

`backslashreplace` is used only on characters that cause `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```py
>>> print u'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''
ï\c\☃"'☃☃"'

>>> print b'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''
�\c\\N{SNOWMAN}"'☃\u2603"'
�
>>> print u'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
\xef\c\\u2603"'\u2603\u2603"'
\xa0
>>> print b'''\xef\c\\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\
... ☃\u2603\"\'\n\xa0'''.decode('latin1').encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
\xef\c\\N{SNOWMAN}"'\xe2\x98\x83\u2603"'
\xa0
```

Answer (score 3):

`\xhh` is an escape character and `\x` is seen as the start of this escape.

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes introduce "escape sequences". `\x` specifically allows you to specify a byte, which is given as two hexadecimal digits after the x. `ef` are two hexadecimal digits, hence you get no error. Double the backslash to escape it, or use a raw string `r"\xeffective"`.

Edit: While the Python console may show you `'\\'`, this *is* precisely what you expect. You just say you expect something else because you confuse the string and its representation. It's a string containing a single backslash. If you were to output it with `print`, you'd see a single backslash.

But the string literal `'\'` is ill-formed (not closed because `\'` is an apostrophe, not a backslash and end-of-string-literal), so `repr`, which formats the results at the interactive shell, does not produce it. Instead it produces a string literal which you could paste into Python source code and get the same string object. For example, `len('\\') == 1`.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I got the impression that the OP's string really was `x = '\xeffective'` and the problem was to turn this back into `y = '\\xeffective'`.

Comment: @DSM Huh, this interpretation didn't occur to me. Possible, but the question is *very* vague. In either case OP seems quite confused about the representation of the string and its value.

Answer (score 1):

The `\x` escape sequence signifies a Unicode character in the string, and `ef` is being interpreted as the hex code. You can sanitize the string by adding an additional `\`, or else make it a raw string (`r'\xeffective'`).

```
>>> r'\xeffective'[0]
'\\'
```

EDIT: You could convert an existing string using the following hack:

```
>>> a = '\xeffective'
>>> b = repr(a).strip("'")
>>> b
'\\xeffective'
```

Comment: Ok, but how to convert variable into 'raw' variable. r'\xeffective' works but if ab = '\xeffective' how can I achieve that?

Comment: @Drachenfels: `r''` ("'raw' string") is only for string *literals* e.g., in your source code. There is no such thing in memory. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844459/4279)

Comment: `'\x'` does *not* signify a Unicode character. `'\xef'` is a single byte (bytestring of length 1). `u'\xef'` is a `ï` Unicode character (`u'\u00ef'`) e.g., in utf-8 encoding it is 2-bytes: `b'\xc3\xaf'`